# Able to setup printer to use LPT1: in Win10 even though port doesn't exist but can't access LPT1?

Tags: windows-10, printing, com, lpt

I have Win10 x64 Pro.  The system doesn't have any `COM` or `LPT` ports, yet when I look at printer properties I have all the normal `LPT1->LPT3`, and `COM1->COM4`.  I assigned the `ABS PDF Driver v400` to `LPT1:` presuming that attempting to write to `LPT1` would redirect to that printer.  Unfortunately it doesn't work.

When I try to access it from the command line I get the following:

```
 >copy con lpt1
 Test<enter>
 The system cannot find the file specified.
 0 file(s) copied.

 >copy con lpt1:
 "lpt1:" is not a recognized device.
 The system cannot find the file specified.

 >type somefile.txt > lpt1:
 The system cannot find the file specified.

 >type somefile.txt > lpt1
 The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have some older software that uses `lpt1:` `lpt2:` and `com1:` devices for output.  **How** can I get Windows to make the `LPT` and `COM` devices available?

*Also*, **why** do they make it available via `Ports` in printer properties when they don't exist.  It only makes sense they did that to emulate those ports, but it's not working?

So I tried the network share method.  I was in settings (manage your device) of `ABS PDF Driver v400` when I did this:

```
 >net use LPT1: "\\mysystemname\ABS PDF Driver v400"
 The command completed successfully.

 >copy con lpt1
 test it.
 ^Z
        1 file(s) copied.
```

At this point the Manage your device in Win10 has gone haywire, where the `printer status` is cycling between 1 and 2 document(s) in queue.  If you open the queue, it's going bonkers constantly refreshing with 1 and 2 documents going back and forth.  Like it's stuck in a loop.  I right clicked and canceled all documents, now it's empty.

I deleted that `LPT1:`, removed the share on `ABS PDF Driver v400` and setup a share to my actual printer `HP Laser Jet M400`.   When I ran my `testit` test, it actually printed.

So there is multiple questions here, but one main question is:

Why do they allow the ports to be chosen in printer ports if they aren't going to emulate them the way "Net Use" does automatically?  There has to be a reason for it.

Comment: Even if your system doesn't have traditional serial and parallel ports, [some others do](https://www.mitacmct.com/EmbeddedSystem_E220_E220). If you had one, would you prefer needing to add it manually instead of the operating system providing it as it used to?

Comment: Get a USB to Parallel Converter. Been there, done that, successfully.

Comment: IIRC those create additional LPT ports to the existing ones. If some legacy SW is hardcoded to use LPT1 could this be made workable?

Comment: The one I had used LPT1. Windows 7 machine. I do not see Parallel printer any more and Seven is gone

Comment: [They do still exist](https://www.printerbase.co.uk/printer-by-feature/parallel-printers.html), but they aren't the only LPT-connected devices out there, and using adapters isn't always possible. TBH I think this question should probably be flagged as out-of-topic - unless there's a Windows engineer willing to share in-house knowledge about the _WHY_ in Windows design, I find it hard to see this could lead to anything but opinions and guesstimations.

Comment: The other thing you can do (done it, works well) is get a Parallel Print Server and put your printer on your network. Works great.   Parallel Printer servers are still readily available.

Comment: With a Print Server, my recollection is that you find the printer on an IP address and do not need LPT1 any longer. There is some old software that deals with LPT1 and that has to be set up.